# Visual Studio no responde al editar cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, cshtml, visual-studio-2022

Hace algunos días tuve un problema eléctrico con mi computadora, adquirí un nuevo equipo, e instale Visual Studio 2022, clone mi proyecto de mi repositorio de GitHub donde lo tenia respaldado, comencé a intentar trabajar y me di cuenta que al intentar editar archivos `.cshtml` (Razor) Visual Studio deja de responder, el IDE se congela y la única forma de cerrar el programa es finalizarlo desde el administrador de tareas, al editar un controlador (`.cs`) o `.js`, `.CSS` VS trabaja bien, guarda los cambios y me permite subirlos a GitHub, con otras extensiones no tengo problema. El proyecto originalmente se creo con VS 2022, y anexo una captura, tomar como ejemplo:

Intento escribir la etiqueta `<form></form>` , y VS comienza a realizar algún proceso y se congela

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado lo siguiente:

- Reparar y reinstalar VS
- Correr como administrador el IDE
- Desactivar el *Run on live analisys*
- Limpiar la cache de VS

Comment: El instalador de VS tiene una opción para reparar el programa, tal vez pueda servir.

Comment: Olvidé agregar lo que he intentado, pero entre las actividades ya lo he reparado y reinstalando

Comment: Revisa el administrador de tareas y revisa si tienes el VS consumiendo algún proceso que te hace eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude resolver mi problema, aplique actualizaciones de Microsoft Windows 11 e instale el SDK .Net 6.0 (v6.0.311), el proyecto funciona de forma normal.
Adjunto el enlace de descarga [aquí](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/es-es/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.311-windows-x64-installer)

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta haciendo click en el check del costado por favor. Saludos.